# Highstock mouseover data window

Tags: highcharts

I have two series charted, on mouseover both data point values appear in a popup window.  Can you set it that only one of the data series is shown inside this box?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to make your question clear, but first, make sure you've tried to answer your own question. One way to clarify your question is to give sample code, and / or sample images. Try to make sure your grammar and spelling are not making your question confusing. Also, it is best to tag your question (like you did). Are there any other tags you might think helpful? CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

It's controlled by `tooltip.shared`, which does this when true:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-true/

When false, you should see individual tooltips:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-false/

In regular HighCharts it defaults to non-shared, but HighStock defaults to shared.

Comment: I add only links to documentation, where parameter is described.
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip and http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.shared